# Are there any Pokémon that lose overall base stats when they evolve?

Tags: pokemon-series

Most Pokémon become more powerful when they evolve, gaining a higher base stat amount in all their stats (HP, attack, defense, special attack, special defense and speed), and a higher base stat total. Are there any Pokémon in any of the mainline games that, after evolving, instead have an equal or lower base stat total as their evolution than as their pre-evolution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Pokémon's base stat total not increasing after evolution happens in only two cases:

- Scyther evolving into Scizor, which trades 40 base Speed for 20 base Attack and 20 base Defense. Scizor has the same base stat total as Scyther, making Scizor the only "side evolution" in Pokémon.
- Nincada "evolving" into Shedinja, which trades 30 base HP and 45 base Defense for 45 base Attack. Thanks to Shedinja's Wonder Guard ability and its fixed 1 HP, its Defense and Special Defense stats are essentially not used. Shedinja still loses 30 base stat total compared to Nincada, however

Comment: MIght be important to note that the Nincada->Shedinja also produces a Ninjask (with higher base stat total than the Nincada)

Comment: For what it's worth, Shedinja's defensive stats *can* potentially matter if you Baton Pass a Substitute to it, or with other edge cases like Mimic into Guard Split.

Comment: I would suggest slightly clarifying the Shedninja; Nincada doesn't evolve into it, but rather a Shedninja 'appears' when you evolve Nincada into Ninjask and have space and a pokeball (post-Gen 3).  It's worth mentioning Shedninja for sure, but it should be more clear it's not *exactly* a direct answer.